# Laravel - rendering inside layout (from controller or ...?)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have setup a general layout for all my views - all fine.

Now, I would like to get some information from database to put in the header, which is part of the layout.

At the moment, the only way I can find out is something like:

```
// OneControler.php
static public function hello()
{
$data['hey'] = 'heeey';
return View::make('layouts.partial.nav', $data);    
}
```

And from inside the layout:

```
// master.blade.php
...
{{ OneController::hello() }}
...
```

This works fine but... I think there must be another way? I don't think loading a controller from inside the view/layout is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use View Composers to help you with this:

```
View::composer(array('your.first.view','your.second.view'), function($view)
{
    $view->with('count', User::count());
});
```

Then in your view `your.first.view` or `your.second.view`, or even your **layout** you can just:

```
{{ $count }}
```

In the array of views, you put the name of the view:

```
View::composer(array('layouts.partial.nav') ...
```

or you can just set it to all views:

```
View::composer(array('*') ...
```

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like a good way to do it! I want it to be available in the layout always... what do I put into the array?

Comment: If you were talking about the composer array, I just edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a variable for all views you can also use share:

```
View::share('name', 'Steve');
```

In your view or layout:

```
{{ $name }}
```